# sugar daddy sent me check for $3000, i’m waiting for it to clear but he’s asking me to send $500 to a friend

Tags: sugar-daddy

so i’ve been messaging a sugar daddy back and forth. we agreed on a certain amount of money a week but he ended up saying he was going to send me 3x the amount of what we agreed on. he told me i was going to do something with that money, a way for him to trust me. basically he ended up saying i would keep the rate we agreed on first and then pay his friend the remainder. i wearily agreed.

so he sent me the check for $3,200 and i’m waiting for it to clear, they estimate 4 days. my sugar daddy is assuring me saying the check will clear and to send $500 to his friend because it’s urgent. something about his daughters health.

is it a scam?

Comment: Of course it's a scam. The cheque will bounce or the money will turn out to be stolen. You'll end up down $500 and potentially in trouble for money laundering too.

Comment: what should i do if i gave them my bank info?

Comment: Contact your bank and tell them what you've done.

Comment: And if @BobbyScon 's link does not answer your question, type "sugar" into the search on box for this site and see if any of the 100+ do.

Comment: BTW, even if the check clears in 4 days, you are still being scammed. Either the money is not really cleared and will reverse, or it is from an account he stole from someone else and you are part of a chain of money laundering. At best you will be out $500. At worst you will be talking to the police or federal agents. (assuming you are in USA)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's a scam. You'll send the $500, the check won't clear, and you'll be out $500 of your own money. This has all the hallmarks of a scam: a request from someone you've never met in person, them "sending" you extra money to send to someone else, and a reason to act urgently - there are all huge red flags.

Step back, and consider that the request makes no sense whatsoever - if this person's friend's daughter really needs the money for some medical emergency, why is he relying on a stranger that he doesn't even "trust" yet to go through this convoluted process, rather than just sending the money himself? There is virtually never a legitimate reason for someone to "give" you money that you're supposed to give to someone else. If you consider possible reasons why this person is involving you in this "situation" with the friend's daughter's medical emergency *at all* in the first place, the only one that makes sense is that you're being scammed. This person supposedly has enough money to send thousands to friends and acquaintances, but can't handle a simple wire transfer?